# Contraction and expansion after constricting flow though a pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

If an orifice is placed inside a pipe with a smaller diameter than the rest of the pipe, fluid will follow a curved path in order to enter the orifice, and then expand.

I was wondering at what distance would the diameter of the flow reach its minimum (the vena contracta) and at what distance after that would the diameter of the flow once again reach the diameter of the pipe.

Comment: + I'm not sure, but I'd [*look here*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orifice_plate), for starters.